# QUERY: sum two columns and order by one in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have the following data set:

```
Country         Points    Bonus_Points
---------------------------------------
United States   1         50
Brazil          3         50
France          7         30
United States   2         25
```

And now would like to query that data set and create a list with the following outcome where bonus points and points get summed up and the list is getting ordered by bonus points.

```
Country         Points    Bonus_Points
---------------------------------------
United States   3         75
Brazil          3         50
France          7         30
```

With

```
=QUERY(A1:C,"select A, B, sum(C) group by A, B order by sum(C) desc", 1)
```

I'm able to sum one column but somehow unable to manage to get the sum for B/points as well.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]See if this helps

```
=QUERY(A1:C,"select A, sum(B), sum(C) group by A order by sum(C) desc label sum(B) 'Points', sum(C) 'Bonus_Points'", 1)
```

Comment: Thank you! Why does =QUERY(A1:C,"select A, D, sum(B), ... not add another column when D would be something like a comment or so that I want to display in addition to the sum?

Comment: It should but you'll have to add it in the group by clause as well: group by A, D

Comment: Thank you, forgot to add it there :)